# starting table cells from right to left

Tags: html, css, forms, right-to-left

I am writing a hebrew webpage and I need to create a form. I need the cells to start from right to left and not from left to right as the default, so when I press the tab button it will go to the left.

I tried the `float:right` CSS attribute in the table and tr td but nothing seems to help. When I finally managed changing the cell order all the cells were pressed together.

Can anyone specify the right attributes I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to apply the [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute rather than monkeying with cell order.

Comment: The `tabindex` attribute is for making exceptions to natural tabbing order, and often a need for it is a symptom of wrong structure. The description of the problem suggests no need for exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

Set the layout direction to right-to-left, most naturally with `<html dir=rtl>`. The [`dir` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/dirlang.html#adef-dir) sets, in addition to directionality of directionally neutral text, the layout order of table columns. So you can write the table cells, containing input elements, in the logical order (first the field to be filled in first, etc.), and the browser will set the cells right to left. So tabbing from the first input field to the second one means going to the left.

Note that `dir=rtl` will also set default alignment to the right, which is normally appropriate for right-to-left languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--set css for div-->
<div class=".swaptable">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
<style>
    .swaptable{
        direction: rtl;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Class names should not begin with a dot. If it does, your CSS selector is incorrect.